# Newly created xamarin forms app doesn't build

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin development. I just tried to create a new Blank Xamarin Forms project in Visual studio. It's really frustrating that this brand new project doesn't build and I can't resolve the issue. I tried to update Xamarin Forms in the Android solution, but it didn't help..

The first error message is: "The type or namespace 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

This Forms project doesnt have a "references" node so I can't reference anything to it...

Any ideas?
Screenshots:

[image: New project]

[image: errors]

Comment: Looks like a problem with either your Xamarin install or the template. Does this happen every time you create a new Forms app?

Also, can you link your version information from here? 
**Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio > Copy Info**

Comment: I installed a Xamarin update just before I started this new project :( I'll send the version information as I get home around 7 pm gmt+2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted every other project but the android one and it works now, I don't need the others for now, so it's good enough for me.

Comment: When you come back to this issue, you might want to make sure you have the recommended Android SDK packages & Android settings: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/installation/#Android

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll definately take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

did you tried to clean & rebuild your solution? Maybe that'll help :)

Comment: Yes, tried rebuilding several times, but explicit clean as well - but I don't think it was needed anyways, as it's a brand new project, as clean as possible :D

Comment: True, but this is my first step at solving those kind of problems :p

Answer (score 1):

Check all your references and make sure they are resolving correctly in each project.